# Solve the recurrence $T(n)=3T(n/3)+n/\log n, T(1)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I tried to solve this by resurrection tree and finally the ultimate series became $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\log_3 n } \frac{n}{\log\left(\frac{n}{3^i}\right)}$$ but I could not solve this. Is there any close form for this series or another effective approach for solving mentioned recurrence relation?

Comment: this sum equals a digamma function

Comment: As usual with these questions, going back to the basics is the most direct route: note that the sequence $$S(k)=3^{-k}T(3^k)$$ solves $S(0)=1$ and $$S(k)=S(k-1)+\frac1{k\log3}$$ hence $$S(k)=1+\frac1{\log3}\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i$$ and since $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i\sim\log k$$ one gets $$T(3^k)\sim 3^k\log_3k=3^k\log_3\log_33^k$$ which is commonly (and incorrectly) translated as $$T(n)\sim n\log_3\log_3n$$

Comment: Do not say "solve" if you only want to get an asymptotic formula for it.  (I'm assuming that book does not require knowledge of the digamma function.)

Comment: Thanks all. i hoped i could get an explicit expression. but later i realized that it is impossible (except that particular attitude which related to digamma function but my book does not require knowledge of this function; as GEdgar said). The question text has used "solve" term too. But presumably it's mean was "get an asymptotic formula"!

Comment: Well, an explicit formula is $$T(3^k)=3^k(1+(\log3)^{-1}H_k)$$ but apart from that...