# Solve the Recurrence : $T(n)=3T(n/3) +\frac{n}{\log(n)}$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

This question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993746/solve-the-recurrence-tn-3tn-3n-log-n-t1-1) but doesn't solve my doubt.

After  Solving the recurrence relation
$$ T(n) = 3T(n/3) + \frac{n}{\log{n}}$$
I get following equation
$$
T(n)=3^kT(n/3^k) + \frac{n}{\log{n}} +\frac{n}{log{\frac{n}{3}}} +\frac{n}{log{\frac{n}{3^2}}} \space\space\ldots \frac{n}{log{\frac{n}{3^k}}}
$$

I don't understand how 
$$ \sum\frac{n}{log{\frac{n}{3^k}}}$$ beats $$3^k$$ asymptotically.

I don't know how to simplify the summation:
$$ \sum\frac{n}{log{\frac{n}{3^k}}}$$

It would be great if you could provide a complete solution.

Comment: Forget the so-called Master theorem and note that $$x_k=3^{-k}T(3^k)$$ solves the recursion $$x_k=x_{k-1}+\frac1{k\log3}$$ hence, for every $k$, $$x_k=x_0+\frac1{\log3}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac1j=\Theta(\log k)$$ that is, $$T(3^k)=\Theta(3^k\log k)$$ from which one usually deduces (although, and this is a feature of the field as it is taught, the implication requires some supplementary hypothesis) that $$T(n)=\Theta(n\log\log n)$$

Comment: $\sum _{i=0}^{\log _3(n)} \frac{n}{\log \left(\frac{n}{3^i}\right)}=\\\sum _{i=0}^{\log _3(n)} -\frac{n}{\log
   \left(\frac{3^i}{n}\right)}=\\\sum _{i=0}^{\log _3(n)} -\frac{n}{\log \left(3^i\right)-\log (n)}=\\\sum
   _{i=0}^{\log _3(n)} -\frac{n}{i \log (3)-\log (n)}=\\\frac{\gamma  n+n \psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log (n)}{\log
   (3)}\right)}{\log (3)}=\\\frac{n H_{-\frac{\log (3 n)}{\log (3)}}}{\log (3)}$ where $H$ is harmonic Number

Comment: @Did I didn't understand your solution previously but I get it now

Comment: @Maruisz Iwaniuk what are $$\gamma$$ and $$\psi$$ and is $$nH$$ subtracting  from $$ \frac{\log{3n}}{\log{3}}$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk How to make the simple computation in my comment more complicated, more notationally involved, more everything except enlightening... :-) I mean, contrary to the OP, I know the steps you followed and I can decipher the notations with which you lost the OP -- and I can state that all this is not useful.

Comment: @SahilSawant. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html

Comment: thanks @MariuszIwaniuk. Actually Did it was my mistake I asked in the question a way for simplifying the summation not realizing that it would be so complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) case 2b, as $\frac{n}{\log(n)} = \Theta(n\log^{-1}(n))$ ($c_{crit} = 1$ and $k = -1$), we have $T(n) = \Theta(n\log\log(n))$.

To know more, you can find [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5273/51a915d7f34f8965c74ecf422e70cd410b52.pdf) useful.

Comment: I read the master's theorem from [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition) by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein. It's not that extensive. Thanks for the answer and much more thanks for the paper it will solve all the doubts.

Comment: A $\Theta$ is missing.

Comment: @Did. Thanks. Updated.